# подсказка при наведение на блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Необходимо повторить подобное[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идея заключается в том, что существует div с некоторым *искусственным* атрибутом, если у блока на который наведен курсор есть подобный атрибут необходимо разместить подсказку со стороны, где есть место(верх/низ).
 **Не предлагайте стандартные подсказки к кнопкам**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 - Tooltips (всплывающие подсказки)</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .btn {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Контент страницы -->
<div class="container text-center">

    <h1 class="h3" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 40px;">Bootstrap 3 - Tooltips (всплывающие подсказки)</h1>

    <button id="btn-tooltip" class="btn btn-danger" title="текст всплывающей подсказки">Кнопка с подсказкой</button>

</div>



<script>
    $('#btn-tooltip').tooltip();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```